# How to add vertical (and horizontal) line in highcharts scatter plot

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

`highcharts` failed to add `vertical line` in the `scatter` plot. Below is one such example -

library(highcharter)

```
Data = data.frame(x = round(rnorm(20) * 100, 2), y = round(rnorm(20) * 100, 2), z = letters[1:20])
hchart(Data, "bubble", hcaes(x, y)) %>%
        hc_yAxis(plotLines = list(value = 0))
```

This plots nothing. Can someone points me towards the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `type = "bubble"` to `type = "scatter"` and `hc_yAxis` as below

```
hchart(Data, "scatter", hcaes(x, y)) %>%
  hc_yAxis(
    plotLines = list(
      list(color = "#252525",
           width = 2,
           value = 0)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but not perfect so I decided to add my own with more information.

You don't have to change the series type from 'bubble' to 'scatter'. It works fine with 'bubble'.

Your code didn't work because, in Highcharts, plotLines needs to be an array of objects. In R **lists** imitate JS' arrays and objects so you need a list of lists. Also, you don't need to define 'color' and 'width'. I don't remember when exactly, but few months ago Highcharts added default values for them and all you need to define is just 'value'.

```
hc_yAxis(plotLines = list(list(value = 10)))
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines

Comment: Im using highcharter 0.7.0 and I cannot get "bubble" to work, please compare hchart(data.frame(x=1:10, y = 1:10), type = "scatter", mapping = hcaes(x = x, y = y)) and type = "bubble". Also, I didn´t say that you have to specify width and value, I just gave some more information :)

Comment: I am not attacking you, I just wanted to extend your answer ;) this is the main idea of StackOverflow. If the author of the question (or anybody else) can get more information and learn something from the second answer, then I am happy to give them one.

Comment: And I compared your data - both series work fine for me.